# Incomplete JSON response using asyncHttpClient.get()

Tags: java, android, json, get, asynchttpclient

I'm using `asyncHttpClient.get()` in a scenario where the response should return a huge amount of data, but the response is incomplete (and unparseable).

Reference link : [asyncHttpResponseHandler.onSuccess](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler.html#onSuccess(int,%20org.apache.http.Header[],%20byte[]))

Here is my code:

```
asyncHttpClient.get(relativeUrl, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headerInfo, byte[] responseData) {
            if (responseData != null) {
                String responseStr = new String(responseData);
                System.out.println("Response",responseStr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Why is the response incomplete?

Comment: what's the status code you are getting in this case?

Comment: maybe you can confirm the response progress with your custom implementation for onProgress method, so that you will get a bit of an idea

Comment: I think your parser is not working, can you post your parser code so that we can have a look in it, and API response also.